# C# SQL - Whats the most efficient way to obtain one result?

Tags: c#, php, sql

As title really.

I want to object just one specific value from a colum on one row of a SQL database.

The PHP code I would use would be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM delivery WHERE id='$id'");
echo mysql_result($result,0);
```

That would get me the price from what ever autoinc id I choose.

As I'm new to C# its quite tricky to get my head around as there seems to be many different methods to obtain the same results.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

*EDIT*

I'm using System.Data.SqlClient as, so far, its done me proud.

Comment: Are you using MYSql with c# as well or have you changed DB?

Comment: Welcome to the 21st century, there are a trillion ways to achieve this, just like in PHP. Any details on your ORM etc?

Comment: How are you talking to your database?  are you using LinqToSQL or the System.Data.SQLClient objects (Connection, Command, DataReader etc)?  Or are you after a plain MS SQL Query?

Comment: I'm using an SQL database and using System.Data.SqlClient. I've got a few queries done with multiple results but finding the quickest and easiest way of obtaining just one simple result from what would be one row and one specified column is proving difficult!

Comment: As you got a SQL db, you should at least check out Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data type of PRICE column you want to retrieve is a scalar value and you'll get only one record then I assume the most efficient way would be ExecuteScalar() method. Here's a little sample code:

```
string conString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=...."
SQLConnection con=new SQLConnection(conString);
SQLCommand cmd=new SQLCOmmand("SELECT price FROM delivery WHERE =@ID",con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value=125//Off course it just a sample value
con.Open();
float price=(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

......
con.Close();//don't forget
```

Comment: This seems a perfect solution. Thank you.

Comment: For a +1, please could you expand the example code to include creation and use of the parameter? *(Rather than just a comment, saying where it goes?)*

Answer (score 0):

for example with ADO.NET.

```
string strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=1"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con); 
int nr = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score -2):

you could always use the TOP function in SQL to retun a single result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT TOP (1) price FROM delivery WHERE id='$id'");
```

I am not sure if this will help you to do what you are looking to do, but I hope it helps.

Comment: And I think we can assume id is unique, so top would be useless.